# What makes disengaged participants tired / exhausted after corporate meetings?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, collaboration

**Why do disengaged people feel tired, fatigued or unfocused after long, "boring" corporate style meetings?** (there is an agenda, but not everyone participates?) Over the years I've observed dozens of meetings where a 6-8 of "optional" people get invited, but only 1-2 people really talk, while the rest are disengaged and are checking email, etc.

Is it related to long period of inactivity, lack of engagement or mirror neurons reading each other's emotions?

Another way to put it : **Why do periods of cognitive inactivity or lack of engagement result in people feeling tired?**

Comment: Do people universally feel tired, fatigued or unfocused after long, "boring" corporate style meetings?

Comment: I've clarified the question to specifically exclude speakers or meeting host. Those people may not feel the effects as acutely as people who are not engaged for an hour.

Comment: I think this could be answered if rephrased to something like "Why do periods of cognitive inactivity or lack of engagement result in people feeling tired?"

Comment: I've updated a question with your suggestion, however, my question specifically relates to having other people present.